# subscribing subject in guard not giving response

Tags: angular, rxjs

The problem is, service which I subscribed in my guard class gets response only few times. No Idea where am I going wrong. will I get some help on this please.

**My service class**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {
    loginStatus = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

**My Component class where subscribed subject and emitted using next()**

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../signin-signup/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin-signup',
  templateUrl: './signin-signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin-signup.component.css'],
})
export class SigninSignupComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{

  subscription :Subscription;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.authService.loginStatus.subscribe(response => {
      this.success = response;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  data={
    email:null,
    password:null
  }
  
  loginMode = true;
  mode = 'signin';
  success : boolean = false;
  status : boolean = false;

  onSwitchMode() { // on click we can which b/w sign in and sign up
    this.loginMode = !this.loginMode; 
    if(!this.loginMode){
      this.mode = 'signup';
    }
    else{
      this.mode = 'signin';
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.data.email = form.value.email;
    this.data.password = form.value.password;
    if(this.mode==="signin"){  //checking mode type and respective data authentication
      if(this.data.email==="admin@test.com" && this.data.password==="admintest"){
        this.status = true;
      }
      else{
        this.status = false;
      }
    }
    else{
      if(this.data.email==="admin@test.com"){
        this.status = false;
      }
      else{
        this.status = true;
      }  
    }
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if(this.status){
        this.authService.loginStatus.next(true);
      }
      else{
        this.authService.loginStatus.next(false);
      }
    },3000);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**My guard class where I subscribed subject**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "./signin-signup/auth.service";

@Injectable({providedIn : 'root'})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService : AuthService,private router: Router){ }

    guard : boolean = false;
    canActivate(
        acticatedRoute : ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        routerState: RouterStateSnapshot
    ):boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> | UrlTree{
        this.authService.loginStatus.subscribe(response=>{
            console.log(response); // not everytime I do get response here           
            this.guard = response;
        });
        if(this.guard){
            return true;
        }
        return this.router.createUrlTree(['/signIn-signUp']);
    }
}
```

**My routing module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { AccountDetailsComponent } from './account-details/account-details.component';
import { PagenotfoundComponent } from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { SigninSignupComponent } from './signin-signup/signin-signup.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'create-account',component:CreateAccountComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'account-details',component:AccountDetailsComponent},
  {path:'signIn-signUp',component:SigninSignupComponent},
  {path:'**', component:PagenotfoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [RouterModule],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving a response because the guard is subscribing *after* `loginStatus` has emitted.  If you want late subscribers to receive prior emissions, you can use a [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) instead of a plain `Subject`:

```js
loginStatus = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

If you want to start with a default value, you can use [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject):

```js
loginStatus = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

---

Note: typically in angular services, its beneficial to hide the "observer side" of the subject, so that consumers cannot call `.next()` directly.  This can be done like this:

```js
private loginStatus = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
public loginStatus$ = this.loginStatus.asObservable();
```